# How to loop through (array, object, etc) until you are at last value - Actionscript-3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, action

Ok, I'm having trouble on how to loop through a series of objects. There are objects within objects within objects. How could you loop through the first object and if there is an object inside that, loop through that one and so on and so forth.

Here is an example,

```
path = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(file.nativePath);

files = path.getDirectoryListing();
```

so files is an array of [File Object]. Array Ex. [File Object],[File Object],[File Object]

I loop through the array and get the File values I need but one of those file object is an Directory, and if it is. I want to loop through it, get the DirectoryListing and repeat until I'm at the end.

Comment: check out recursive functions

Answer (score 1):

As Eric said, you may use recursive, here is an example

```
var f : File = new File();
f.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFolderSelected);
f.browseForDirectory("Choose a directory");


protected function onFolderSelected(event:Event):void
{

    var targetFile:File = event.target as File;

    var files:Array = getFiles(targetFile);//the all files inthe folder

}

private function getFiles(file:File):Array
{
    var files:Array = [];

    if (file.isDirectory)
    {
        var temp:Array = file.getDirectoryListing();

        for each (var tFile:File in temp)
        {
            files = files.concat(getFiles(tFile));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        files.push(file);
    }

    return files;
}
```

Comment: As a caution: be careful with how you construct recursive functions. Incredibly easy to end up in an infinite function loop and get a stack overflow error. This function appears to be written well enough, though.

Comment: Thanks guys, What I'm trying to do is make a treeview type thing. Know anything of some libraries or some code? Don't want to do it in flex and want to stay in flash as3